# Why did Doom3 switch column and row major matrices?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've been making the valiant attempt to grok the doom 3 source code. One of the things I've stumbled across is the matrix class used throughout the rest of the solution. It's fairly simple code to follow, but there was a decision made that I haven't been able to comprehend. They decided to mix Column and Major row majors for different sizes.

- The 3x3 Matrix is column major
- Every other matrix is row major (I think - haven't checked them all)

Does anyone know why this decision might have been made? Since OpenGL is column major, I would think it would make sense to just use column major?

Comment: I'm not a graphics programmer, but I think row major is more typical in code I've seen that manipulates 2d arrays. So maybe its purely for maintainability.

Comment: Row-major/column-major have vastly different effects on cache behaviour, depending on what types of operations are being performed on the matrices.

Comment: @doug row major is natural in C. Column major is natural in Fortran.

Comment: It might be because there were multiple people working on the engine. It may depend on the actual use of the matrices. If the matrices are used in the graphics part, which uses OpenGL, the column major order is a way to go. However for different uses the row major order might be better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like Oli Charlesworth already commented this might be a decision to improve caching behaviour. OpenGL's matrices are column major because on the client side you're more interested in the columns than the rows (the columns form the base of a coordinate system). If however the matrices are used for calculations like in physics or collision detection, a lot of operations will be row major. So this strongly depends on the kind of operations mostly performed on the matrix in question. The Doom3 engine makes heavy use of [Plücker coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates), so choosing the right memory layout has a very strong effect on overall performance and a simple switch between matrix majority may add/remove a significant number of operations involved.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess:

If I remember correctly, the transformation matrix (which is 3x3) is the matrix you need most for OpenGL. Since OpenGL is column major it makes sense to keep the game-internal representation column major too, so you don't have to do additional work everytime you want to pass a 3x3 matrix to OpenGL.

Keeping the other matrices row major was probably a design decision. Maybe they've re-used code from other games which already use row major, or their programmers are just more comfortable working with it.
Another possibility is that a lot of the operations they do on the other matrices predominantly make use rows instead of columns. Row major then provides you with a better memory layout and faster access times.
It might also be that the file formats they use store matrices as row major.

It's a lot of "might be" and "if", but it's an approach, at least.